# How to bring Chrome browser to front and maximize in selenium 3.4?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I tried the following but did'nt work;

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
```

Could someone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your ChromeDriver and use `maximize()` like

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "PATH/TO/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--test-type");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

or use the below two line instead of `maximize()`;

```
driver.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(0, 0));
driver.manage().window().setSize(new org.openqa.selenium.Dimension(1280, 800));
```

Comment: @Raa I pushed an answer for you. Can you please check it and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: How do u bring the browser to front?

Comment: When the driver is initialized with new keyword and navigate to the browser.

Comment: @Raa you can also try `((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.focus();");` to focus on the top.

Comment: @Raa if it is really helpful for you then Vote up and Tick mark the answer. so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will first switch to the first window it finds with the title of the drivers windows (essentially focusing on it), and then maximize it per Ali's answer.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.Title)
                    .Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use maximized, start-maximized which is quite reliable for Chrome.

```
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
```

## Full code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> preferences = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

preferences.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] { "Adobe Flash Player", "Chrome PDF Viewer" });
preferences.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
preferences.put("password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", preferences);
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("start-maximized");

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverFilePath);
options.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--disable-extensions"));
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
```